# FIWARE Orion ld in Kubernetes .Orion ld container always restarted

Tags: kubernetes, fiware-orion

when i am trying start FIWARE Orion ld in Kubernetes. But Orion ld container always restarted.
Here is the:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fiware-orionld
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: orionld
      tier: app
  template:
    metadata:
      name: fiware-orion
      labels:
        app: orionld
        tier: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo:3.6
        args: ["--nojournal"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017

      - name: orion
        image: fiware/orion-ld
        args: ["-dbhost", "localhost:27017", "-logLevel", "INFO"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1026
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fiware-orion
  labels:
    app: orionld
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 1026      
     targetPort: 8080
     nodePort: 31515 
  selector:
    app: orionld
    tier: app
```

I am getting these errors:
a) Warning  BackOff    4s (x6 over 2m9s)    kubelet, spl1266   Back-off restarting failed container

and in logs:

b) time=Wednesday 05 Feb 17:40:37 2020.932Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=orionldServiceInit.cpp[298]:orionldServiceInit | msg=orionldContextInit failed: Unable to download context https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context.jsonld

Comment: I used your `YAML` definition and besides wrong `targetPort` everything seems to work fine. How was your cluster created? Are you able to ping internet sites when inside a pod? Please provide output of command `$ kubectl describe FIWARE_POD`

Comment: $ kubectl describe fiware-orionld-59c4f84cdf-2nss7
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "fiware-orionld-59c4f84cdf-2nss7"

Comment: I'm sorry. I mistyped the command. Correct command should be `$ kubectl describe pod FIWARE_POD`

Comment: the cluster created in local and it's a single node stateless  application.  calico used for notwork and used also taint.

Comment: Do you have internet access inside a pod?

Comment: Normal   Started    16m                 kubelet, spl1266   Started container mongo
  Normal   Pulling    14m (x4 over 16m)   kubelet, spl1266   Pulling image "fiware/orion-ld"
  Normal   Pulled     13m (x4 over 15m)   kubelet, spl1266   Successfully pulled image "fiware/orion-ld"
  Normal   Created    13m (x4 over 15m)   kubelet, spl1266   Created container orion
  Normal   Started    13m (x4 over 15m)   kubelet, spl1266   Started container orion
  Warning  BackOff    69s (x52 over 15m)  kubelet, spl1266   Back-off restarting failed container

Comment: i think not ....because that container restarted every second

Comment: You can check if you have internet access with another pod like this: [Busybox](https://github.com/ipedrazas/k8s-lskp-demo/blob/master/busybox-pod.yaml) and commands: `$ kubectl exec -it busybox -- /bin/sh` and inside `$ ping google.com`

Comment: pods can't access the internet..

Comment: So this should be the issue why your pod is failing.

Comment: So Dawid how to solve this any solutions...like how to provide the internet access and solve pod falling.

Comment: The issues that you are having can be difficult to pinpoint. How exactly did you create this Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Actually same thing create in using one vm, it's working..but i am trying to run in local system.it's not working.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Orion-LD context broker downloads the Core Context during start-up. This is crucial for its function and If this download fails, the broker cannot work and therefore exits. This is more or less what the error message in the log says. However, your issue is clearly about the network and not about the broker itself.

Comment: @RakeshRoutray what do you mean by `but i am trying to run in local system.it's not working.` Can you tell more about you `local system`?